# createReadStream without path

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

I'm new to programming and web development, and even I'm not native English speaker so my explanation might be hard to understand.

I'm using aws sdk, aws s3, apollo server, apollo client, react and node
when file is sending to a apollo server from a client, a server destructure file to create readable stream so I can upload file to s3.
in node filesystem module docs fs.createReadStream method need path but, my code works without path

I just did createReadStream() without any argument. And it works fine so I can upload the file to s3

```
let { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
let stream = createReadStream();

// don't mind Bucket field
s3.upload({
  Bucket: 'myBucket',
  Key: 'images/' + filename,
  Body: stream,
  ContentType: mimetype
});
```

Why this works without path argument?
Am I missing something?

Comment: You're destructuring `createReadStream` from `file`, so it is very likely that the method is overridden from the standard method provided by the `fs` module, and the file path is likely already bound to the overridden method. Just an educated guess though, would need to know where `file` comes from in your code to be sure ;)

Comment: @Jaxx The file comes from html input (type file). I also research some after I posted this question. I figured out the apollo upload developer made that the method doesn't need any arguments

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
let { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
let stream = createReadStream();

// don't mind Bucket field
s3.upload({
  Bucket: 'myBucket',
  Key: 'images/' + filename,
  Body: createReadStream(),
  ContentType: mimetype
});
```